# How do I correctly write the following URL in RegEx

Tags: regex, url, kissmetrics

A non-dev here, but I need some help with writing a Regex for a URL -

https://example.co.uk/checkout/order-received/210553/?key=wc_order_57960575c7d73

- In order to track it in Kissmetrics, so far I have gotten to

https://example.co.uk/checkout/order-received/?([\da-z.-]+)/

But I feel really stuck, can someone lend me a hand?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [`https://example\.co\.uk/checkout/order-received/\d+/\?[^/]+`](https://regex101.com/r/lC1jD0/1)? Or even anchor it as [`^https://example\.co\.uk/checkout/order-received/\d+/\?[^/]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/lC1jD0/2).

Answer (score 0):

The regex you want is `https:\/\/example\.co\.uk\/checkout\/order-received\/\d+\/\?key=wc_order_[\da-z]+`.

What this will do is match the first part of the URL as a literal string, then the order number as an abitrary string of digits. After that, it escapes the question mark (as question marks have a specific meaning in regex) and matches the query string, including the end bit (`[\da-z]`, of course, refers to a string composed of both letters and numbers).